# Suggestions for Project structure in AzureDevops

Tags: version-control, azure-devops, project-structure

We have 7 products in our organization. For the development of each of the application, we have configuration/creation scripts in the form of Powershell, Json, SQL, YAML scripts files and so on. We want to maintain these scripts in Git source control system in Azure Devops.

Could anyone suggest me a good structure to maintain these scripts in Azure Devops under a single repository?

For example:

- Product 1 (main folder)

  - Powershell Scripts (subfolder)
  - SQL scripts (sub folder)
- Product 2 (main folder)

  - Powershell Scripts (subfolder)
  - SQL scripts (sub folder)

We are at core a database administration team and going forward we would want to keep everything related to SQL server in source control (for example -sql server jobs associated with each VM).

Comment: If that structure works for you, isn't it then good? Without knowing all the details, it's pretty difficult to suggest anything. The requirement (based on what you've written) sounds pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store everything in one git repository it is ok, you can consider have gir repo per project.
The folder structure with you can use is reflection of vm's you have and place where you store it in vm's. So if you will be doing some automation etc you can easy copy and version one way ot another the corresponding code to place where it is on vm's.